# Comparison of different glassy matrices for protein immobilization at room temperature

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-binding

I am completely new to protein biology experiments. I care about experiments where proteins are immobilized near a surface with the help of a glassy matrix or similar materials.

I am looking for a reference that will allow me to compare the performance of various matrices in immobilizing proteins at room temperature. In particular, I want to know which matrices are the best at limiting protein tumbling at room temperature.

In particular, I am interested in matrices that outperform Polylysine matrices at room temperature by a good margin, if that's possible.

I am aware that the melting point of the glassy matrices is probably a good proxy for their ability to immobilize proteins. So perhaps a reference describing the melting points of these matrices would be enough.

If this is more appropriate in the Chemistry forum, let me know.

Comment: Hmmm. I am sure that someone will have looked at it, probably in a commercial field, so there could well be difficulties finding this information with IP concerns etc for companies.